# I can't send UDP packet from Android to Arduino

Tags: android, arduino, wifi

I am trying to send UDP packets from Android app to Arduino using Wifi Shield, but I can't, it throws an exception (Ex3).
I want to communicate an Android phone with Arduino, to send commands with this Shield.

Here is the Android code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String udpMsg = "hello world from UDP client ";
    DatagramSocket ds = null;
    Button bt;
    TextView tv;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
         tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        runUdpClient();
    }

    private static final int UDP_SERVER_PORT = 1050;

    private void runUdpClient() {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "E",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {
                        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
                        String str = et.getText().toString();
                        ds = new DatagramSocket();
                        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.16");
                        DatagramPacket dp;
                        dp = new DatagramPacket(str.getBytes(), udpMsg.length(),
                                serverAddr, UDP_SERVER_PORT);
                        dp.setData(str.getBytes());

                        ds.send(dp);

                        Log.d("Ok","Ok");

                    } catch (SocketException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Ex",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Ex1",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Ex2",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Ex3",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (ds != null) {

                            ds.close();
                        }
                    }
             }
          });


    }
}
```

And this is the Arduino code:

```
include <SPI.h>
include <WiFi.h>
include <WiFiUdp.h>

char ssid[] = "MySSid";
char pass[] = "00000000";
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

unsigned int localPort = 1050;      // local port to listen on

char packetBuffer[255]; //buffer to hold incoming packet
char  ReplyBuffer[] = "acknowledged";       // a string to send back

WiFiUDP Udp;

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present"); 
    // don't continue:
    while(true);
  } 

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:    
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  } 
  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  printWifiStatus();

  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  Udp.begin(localPort);  
}

void loop() {

  // if there's data available, read a packet
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if(packetSize)
  {   
    Serial.print("Received packet of size ");
    Serial.println(packetSize);
    Serial.print("From ");
    IPAddress remoteIp = Udp.remoteIP();
    Serial.print(remoteIp);
    Serial.print(", port ");
    Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());

    // read the packet into packetBufffer
    int len = Udp.read(packetBuffer,255);
    if (len >0) packetBuffer[len]=0;
    Serial.println("Contents:");
    Serial.println(packetBuffer);

    // send a reply, to the IP address and port that sent us the packet we received
 /*   Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
    Udp.write(ReplyBuffer);
    Udp.endPacket();*/
   }
}


void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

I think the problem is in **ds.send(dp);**

Here is the stacktrace:

```
06-23 13:24:03.896: W/System.err(5915): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
06-23 13:24:03.897: W/System.err(5915):     at java.net.DatagramPacket.setData(DatagramPacket.java:183)
06-23 13:24:03.898: W/System.err(5915):     at java.net.DatagramPacket.<init>(DatagramPacket.java:75)
06-23 13:24:03.898: W/System.err(5915):     at java.net.DatagramPacket.<init>(DatagramPacket.java:97)
06-23 13:24:03.898: W/System.err(5915):     at java.net.DatagramPacket.<init>(DatagramPacket.java:118)
06-23 13:24:03.898: W/System.err(5915):     at com.example.arduino.Arduino$1.onClick(Arduino.java:52)
06-23 13:24:03.899: W/System.err(5915):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
06-23 13:24:03.899: W/System.err(5915):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
06-23 13:24:03.900: W/System.err(5915):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-23 13:24:03.900: W/System.err(5915):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-23 13:24:03.901: W/System.err(5915):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-23 13:24:03.901: W/System.err(5915):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
06-23 13:24:03.902: W/System.err(5915):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 13:24:03.902: W/System.err(5915):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-23 13:24:03.902: W/System.err(5915):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
06-23 13:24:03.903: W/System.err(5915):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
06-23 13:24:03.903: W/System.err(5915):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please detail from which line of code the exception is being thrown, what exception is being thrown and anything else that might be pertinent to this problem...

Comment: The exception that is being thrown is:
 catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Ex3",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();






Because, I see the toast "Ex3". Maybe is a problem with socket. Anyway, I am not sure if it's correct this way to communicate both devices (using the Wifi Shield).

Comment: please show us the stacktrace

Comment: You will also get a network on main thread exception on newer devices, as your program is improperly structured.

Comment: I am not sure which is the properly structured.

Is it possible to communicate both devices via ad-hoc without use my router as a access point? Or I need use the router as access point? 
I'm really confused :S

Comment: check my code example there
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649156/udp-sending-on-android4-0-and-before-versions

Answer (score 0):

have you set the following Permissions in your Manifest file?

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"
```

Comment: Yes, I have, but it always throws exception.

Comment: you should read the reference for [DatagramPacket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramPacket.html#DatagramPacket%28byte[],%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29) and then step through the code with the debugger.

Comment: The second two permissions are likely unnecessary, please justify their inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the stacktrace and your code, the exception is thrown at the line:

```
dp.setData(str.getBytes());
```

but, looking at your code, you don't need to do the `setData()` as you're already giving it to the constructor. You may try without that line.